# Can we study all the genes of one human being?

Tags: genetics

Considering the fact that a new-born child gets 23 chromosomes containing DNA and genes from each of his parents and then 23 chromosomes from those 46 chromosomes of the new-born child will be transmitted to his child, I am wondering do all the people have the same 46 chromosomes or all have different chromosomes ( that's another thing that some genes present in the DNA of chromosomes don't express themselves. Of course, they are present there, no? )

If all of us have same chromosomes then can we study those genes present in 46 chromosomes to find out ALL the characters one person can have?